# Find a GameObjects Vector3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Recently I have been working on a save/load-function. What I want to do is save the current `Vector3` after the button "Save" has been pressed. However, I can't seem to figure out how to find a `GameObjects` `Vector3`.

There is a lot of tutorials on the internet but they are all in JS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `gameObject`'s `Vector3` is its `transform.position`. So if you have a reference to it you can just use:

```
Vector3 lastPosition = gameObject.transform.position;
```

Or if the save script is on the `gameObject` its self, you can just reference the transform directly:

```
Vector3 lastPosition = transform.position;
```

More info in the [Unity Docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html).

Comment: The error is probably due to the typo in the answer, postition=>position.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand clearly what you want but you can save vector3 by saving x, y, z separately as floats. Visit [this](http://coffeebreakcodes.com/save-and-load-game-unity3d/) page to see how to save your data. I hope you didn't ask "how to find my GameObject?" :)

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar issue. This worked for me:

```
    public GameObject GO;
    public Vector3 GOsV3;
    void Start()
    {
    GOsV3 = new Vector3 (GO.transform.position.x, GO.transform.position.y, GO.transform.position.z); 
    }
```